# Hosting WebAPI in Windows-Service crashes on first attempt

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, self-hosting

I have an console-app with hosted WebAPI (HttpSelfHostServer).

In the console-app I have Controllers that query data from SQL-Server.

The console-app works without problems (from fiddler and a Windows_client)
Now I want to host the WebAPI (HttpSelfHostServer) in a Windows-Service.

Therefore I have created a Service-Project and referenced the Controllers in console-app-dll so that the controllers should be found.

To have a minimal chance to debug, I write some information in the event log from the windows service.

I can start and stop the windows-service without problems.
It also seems as that the httpselfhost is started and active.

**Problem:
- By first attempt to the url, the service crashes hard with:**

```
System.NullReferenceException (eventlog-entry to .net RunTime) 

Anwendung: WS_MatrixGuide.exe
Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319
Beschreibung: Der Prozess wurde aufgrund einer unbehandelten Ausnahme beendet.
Ausnahmeinformationen: **System.NullReferenceException**
Stapel:
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__5(System.Object)
   bei System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   bei System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   bei System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   bei System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I have tried for days to solve the problem, and I am desperate.

As I am not able to debug the service, I don't know where exactly the crash occurs.

I think, the start of the self-host in the windows-service works and the host also is reachable (as it crashes by first access).

So.. maybe I did something completely wrong in the service or I missed something important..

As the console-app works without problems, I post in the following only the code from the windows-service:
**Code to Windows-Service:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports KA_MatrixGuide.Controllers ' Verweis auf Controller in KA_MatrixGuide (Konsolenanwendung) erstellen
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Web.Http.SelfHost ' Self Hosting
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.IO
Public Class WS_MatrixGuide
    Private SH As ServiceHost
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.ServiceName = "WS_MatrixGuide"
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Vor SH = new...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
        SH = New ServiceHost(GetType(WS_MatrixGuide))
        AddHandler SH.Faulted, AddressOf SH_Faulted
       EventLog.WriteEntry("Vor Dim config...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
        Dim config As New HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://127.0.0.1:21212")
       EventLog.WriteEntry("Vor Config-Routes...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
          name:="DefaultApi", _
          routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
          defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
        )
        'Tracing-Info's in Event-Log schreiben...
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Vor Using Server...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
        Using server As New HttpSelfHostServer(config)
            ' Objekte zu Controllern erstellen (Interface für Zugriff)
            Dim SQL_C As Type = GetType(KA_MatrixGuide.Controllers.SQLController)
            Dim Beauty_C As Type = GetType(KA_MatrixGuide.Controllers.BeautyController)
            Dim Freizeit_C As Type = GetType(KA_MatrixGuide.Controllers.FreizeitController)
            Dim Gourmet_C As Type = GetType(KA_MatrixGuide.Controllers.GourmetController)
            Dim Konfiguration_C As Type = GetType(KA_MatrixGuide.Controllers.KonfigurationController)
            Dim Empfehlungen_C As Type = GetType(KA_MatrixGuide.Controllers.EmpfehlungenController)
           Try
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Vor Server.OpenAsync...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
                server.OpenAsync().Wait()
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Nach Server.OpenAsync...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
            Catch aggEx As AggregateException
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Fehler beim Laden des Servers (httpSelfHostServer)...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
            End Try
            'Console.WriteLine()
            'Console.WriteLine("Enter-Taste drücken, um die Konsolen-Anwendung zu beenden.")
            'Console.ReadLine()
            'AddHandler server.Faulted, AddressOf Server_Faulted ' => es gibt kein Server.Faulted
        End Using
        'EventLog.WriteEntry("WS_MatrixGuide wurde gestartet", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Vor SH.Open...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
        SH.Open()
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Nach SH.Open...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        Dim Infomeldung As String = "WS_MatrixGuide wurde gestoppt"
        EventLog.WriteEntry(Infomeldung, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information)
        SH.Close()
        SH = Nothing
    End Sub
    Private Sub SH_Faulted() ' Eigener Fehlerhandler
        Dim Fehlermeldung As String = "Fehler bei Ausführung von WS_MatrixGuide. Service wurde gestoppt"
        EventLog.WriteEntry(Fehlermeldung, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error)
       Dim cMsg As String = "Fehler bei der Ausführung von WS_MatrixGuide. Der Service wurde gestoppt."
        Dim SMTPMail As New SmtpClient
        SMTPMail.Host = "zrhms200" 
        SMTPMail.Port = 25 ' Standard-Port
        Dim msg As New MailMessage
        msg.From = New MailAddress("Service@matso.ch") 
        msg.To.Add("fredy.wenger@matso.ch")
        msg.Subject = cMsg
        msg.Body = cMsg
        SMTPMail.Send(msg)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm working with VS2013, VB.NET and Win 8.1.

The .net RunTime is installed, all actual updates are installed.

**Any help will highly appreciated**

**Thanks a lot for a first fast answer**

Fredy

Answer (score 3):

Answering very late to your answer, but still thought it might be useful to you.

You are hosting the server **inside using**, which will be **disposed** immediately after the method execution. Try to remove the below statement and that would resolve your problem.

`Using server As New HttpSelfHostServer(config)`

Comment: Thanks for your (unfortunately too) late answer.
In the meantime, I have rewritten the service to Owin (and.. it works:-).

But your answer is interesting generally...
Further question to your answer:
If I **remove** the Using server ... statement, how can I access the server (server.OpenAsync().Wait)?
Or did you mean **change** the Statement (to Dim server as New HttpSelfHostServer(config)... or..what...)?
Thanks for your Time

Comment: You, sir, just solved me a LOT of trouble!!! I've been scratching my head over a set of code that worked over a console but not a windows service for a little while now :=)